# Pandas select three rows per ID amongst varying number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset of 100s of people who have been followed up over varying amounts of time (up to 8 observations per person) and have completed a bunch of tests. The time values are always in an integer sequence for each ID. The goal of my project is to examine these changes in individuals, while sampling each person's data across 3 equally spaced intervals from all their available data. Here is a snapshot of the dataset, with just two tests for brevity.

```
    dict = {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
        "Time": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
        "AlBa": [5, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 7, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1],
        "Tiri": [4, 3, 2, 10, 9, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4]
    }
    
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    print(df_test)

    ID  Time AlBa Tiri
0    1     1   5   4
1    1     2   2   3
2    1     3   1   2
3    2     1   8  10
4    2     2   7   9
5    2     3   6   5
6    2     4   5   4
7    3     1   9   5
8    3     2   7   4
9    3     3   6   3
10   3     4   4   2
11   3     5   2   1
12   4     1   3   4
13   4     2   1   4
```

I want to sample each person's data across 3 equally spaced intervals from all their available data, leading to three data points per ID. Accordingly, ID1 gets included because they have exactly three observations. ID 4 gets excluded because they have only two observations. For individuals with more than three, but an odd number of observations (e.g., ID3), I want to keep scores from their first (time 1), last (here, time 5), and middle observation (here, time 3). For individuals with more than three, but an even number of observations (e.g., ID2), I want to keep their first (time 1), last (here, time 4), and find the average of the middle two observations (here, average of times 2 and 3). The final dataset should look like this:

```
   ID  Time  AlBa Tiri
0   1   1.0  5.0   4
1   1   2.0  2.0   3
2   1   3.0  1.0   2
3   2   1.0  8.0  10
4   2   2.5  6.5   7
5   2   4.0  5.0   4
6   3   1.0  9.0   5
7   3   3.0  6.0   3
8   3   5.0  2.0   1
```

What is the best way to code this in Pandas? I have data with anywhere between 1 and 8 observations per person.

Comment: Are the `Time` values always an integer sequence 1...n?

Comment: Yes they are in an integer sequence for each ID. I have updated my question.

Comment: Please double-check your output, I'd compute 6.5 in place of your 7.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using aggregation per group ([`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)) with `first`/`median`/`last`, then filtering the IDs with [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html), and reshaping with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
g = df_test.groupby('ID')
s = g.size()

out = (g.agg(['first', 'median', 'last'])
        .loc[lambda d: s[s>2].index]  # remove groups with < 2 values
        .stack().reset_index()
        #.drop(columns=['level_1'])
      )
```

Note that median take the mid-point of the **sorted** values, if you want the mid-point by position, use a custom function:

```
def mid_point(s):
    return s.iloc[(len(s)-1)//2:len(s)//2+1].mean()

g = df_test.groupby('ID')
s = g.size()
out = (g.agg(['first', mid_point, 'last'])
        .loc[lambda d: s[s>2].index]
         .stack().reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID level_1  Time  AlBa  Tiri
0   1   first   1.0   5.0   4.0
1   1  median   2.0   2.0   3.0
2   1    last   3.0   1.0   2.0
3   2   first   1.0   8.0  10.0
4   2  median   2.5   6.5   7.0
5   2    last   4.0   5.0   4.0
6   3   first   1.0   9.0   5.0
7   3  median   3.0   6.0   3.0
8   3    last   5.0   2.0   1.0
```

As noted by @Lahcen in comments, you can also pre-filter before the `groupby.agg` with:

```
out = (df_test[df_test.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count').gt(2)]
        .groupby('ID').agg(['first', 'median', 'last'])
        .stack().reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
      )
```

The difference is that in one case you reuse the `groupby` object (which is faster), but filter after the computation (which is slower). In this alternative you have to compute the `groupby` twice but avoid aggregating unnecessarily. The best approach might depend on the number of groups and the proportion of groups with less than 3 values. To be tested on the real data.

Comment: A one liner: `df[df.groupby('ID').ID.transform('count') >= 3].groupby('ID').agg(['first', 'median', 'last']).stack().reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])`

Comment: @Lahcen thank you, I'm aware of this alternative, but this requires to compute twice the `groupby`, which is why I chose to use intermediates reusing the same `groupby` :) This might be a better approach if most of the data will be discarded though

Comment: Ahaa I see now, nice !

Comment: @Lahcen I added a note, thanks again for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant and efficient way:

```
ids = df_test.groupby("ID")

new_dfs = []
for name, sub_df in ids:
    if len(sub_df) < 3:
        continue
    first_row = pd.DataFrame(sub_df.iloc[0]).T  # Store the first row
    sub_df.drop(sub_df.index[0], inplace=True)
    last_row = pd.DataFrame(sub_df.iloc[-1]).T
    sub_df.drop(sub_df.index[-1], inplace=True)
    mean = pd.DataFrame(sub_df.median()).T
    new_df = pd.concat([first_row, mean, last_row])
    new_df["ID"] = name
    new_dfs.append(new_df)

new_df = pd.concat(new_dfs)
```